# CSS: When to use right: 0px and when to use float: right?

Tags: css, alignment, css-float

I am currently learning CSS and was wondering when to use `right: 0px;` and when to use `float: right;`. I understand that you have to set the `position`attribute in order to be able to use `right: 0px;`, but I was just wondering when to use which one?

I heard that `float` is bad?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are learning CSS, you must use `padding` and `margin` whenever you can, this might take some time to master, but it will keep things simple in relation with the overall flow of the elements (in relation to one another).

If you cant get the desire result with `padding` and `margin`, then you can use `float` property (`float: right;`, `float: none;`, ...), but use this only when you want two elements share horizontal space.

### To sum up:

### 1. I was just wondering when to use which one?

Use `padding` and `margin` as your first option, and if that is not getting you the desire result use `float`, and if that still is not what you want, you can try advanced CSS features such as flexbox and table layout.

### 2. I heard that float is bad?

Well it is not bad at all, just it can be easy to overuse, and that will make your code more complicated.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP tho

Answer (score 1):

Floated elements are in a sense in their own flow. They are actually MOVED and will interact with each other and to a certain extent the regular flow of content ( the wrap around effect you see).

Though a floated element is out of the regular flow, you can use several methods to clear it so that it's container doesn't collapse

If the elements are meant to interact with each other, use floats. If an element is independent of the content around it or all dependent on a common parent, use absolute positioning.